# Iterate the value into Javascript in Flask html template

Tags: javascript, html

I am passing `data` to my flask html template. In the html, there is a Javascript, where I need iterate value. `data` looks Like,

`data[0] = 2, data[1] = 3, data[3] = 5, data[2] = .36` so on

index.html :-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>


  <div id="chart_div"></div>




{% for i in data %}

<script>
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBackgroundColor);

function drawBackgroundColor() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('number', 'X');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

      data.addRows([
        [{{i[2]}}, {{i[6]}}]
      ]);

      var options = {
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time'
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Popularity'
        },
        backgroundColor: '#f1f8e9'
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>

{% endfor %}


</html>
```

I want to iterate the value here,

```
data.addRows([
            [{{i[2]}}, {{i[6]}}]
          ]);
```

It should be like,

```
data.addRows([
            [0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1]
          ]);
```

But, it is iterating the whole script.

Answer (score 0):

The entire script is inside of the for loop, so the templating engine will duplicate the script as many times as there are entries in data.